# Extracting string with the help of function

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

Actually I have data frames of clickstream with about 4 million rows. I have many columns and two of them are based on URL and Domain. I have a dictionary and want to use it as a condition. For example: If the domain is equal to `amazon.de` and Url contains a Keyword `pillow` then the column will have a value `pillow`. And so on.

```
dictionary_keywords = {"amazon.de": "pillow", "rewe.com": "apple"}

ID   Domain                  URL
1    amazon.de               www.amazon.de/ssssssss/exapmle/pillow
2    rewe.de                 www.rewe.de/apple
```

The expected output should be the new column:

```
ID   Domain                  URL                                    New_Col
1    amazon.de               www.amazon.de/ssssssss/exapmle/pillow  pillow
2    rewe.de                 www.rewe.de/apple                       apple
```

I can manually use .str.contain method but need to define a function which takes the dictionary key and value as a condition.

Something like this `df[df['domain] == 'amazon.de'] & df[df['url'].str.contains('pillow')`

But I am not sure. I am new in this.

Comment: learn to use regular expression (RegEx), life will be easier

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: @jorijnsmit I just edited the question and i added what I am trying to do so far... But i am new and not really understanding how to use the dictionary as a condition.

Comment: Input and output don't match. You have `"rewe.com": "apple"` in the dictionary but `"rewe.de"` and `"Apple"` (uppercase A) in the DataFrame.

Comment: @alec_djinn Thanks for pointing it out... I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I prefer to solve this kind of problem is by using `df.apply()` by row (`axis=1`) with a custom function to deal with the logic.

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary_keywords = {"amazon.de": "Pillow", "rewe.de": "Apple"}
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Domain':['amazon.de','rewe.de'],
    'URL':['www.amazon.de/ssssssss/exapmle/pillow', 'www.rewe.de/apple']
})

def f(row):
    global dictionary_keywords
    try:
        url = row['URL'].lower()
        domain = url.split('/')[0].strip('www.')
        if dictionary_keywords[domain].lower() in url:
            return dictionary_keywords[domain]
    except Exception as e:
        print(row.name, e)
    return None #or False, or np.nan

df['New_Col'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
print(df)

      Domain                                    URL New_Col
0  amazon.de  www.amazon.de/ssssssss/exapmle/pillow  Pillow
1    rewe.de                      www.rewe.de/apple   Apple
```

Comment: It seems promising and probably this is so far the best solution but I guess it might take longer if there are about millions of rows... or?

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanShahid longer than what? df.apply is fast. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Just curious because of function but its the best solution. Thanks for this :)

Comment: You could make it faster by stripping down the function. If you have a use case for that.